Plotted equations are halting at x=5 with PGFPlots
I am trying to plot two equations using PGFPlots. They are -(x-7)^2+12 and (x-6)^2-2. However, the resulting graph refuses to draw beyond x=5. I've looked over the code I am using to configure the plot and nothing appears to be causing the issue.
Minimal Working Example:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
        xtick = {0,2,...,10},
        extra y ticks = 0,
        ymin = -5, ymax = 15,
        ytick = {-5,0,...,15},
        samples = 100,
    ]
        \addplot[color=red]{-(x-7)^2+12};
        \addplot[color=blue]{(x-6)^2-2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Screenshot of the resulting graph.


Welcome to TeX.SX1 Try adding domain={0:10} (which is domain={-5:5} per default).

PGFPlots sets domain={-5:5} per default which restricts the plot to -5 ≤ x ≤ 5. But you can change this easily:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
        xtick = {0,2,...,10},
        extra y ticks = 0,
        ymin = -5, ymax = 15,
        ytick = {-5,0,...,15},
        samples = 100,
        domain = {0:10}
    ]
        \addplot[color=red]{-(x-7)^2+12};
        \addplot[color=blue]{(x-6)^2-2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

(You can also use this option with the \addplot commands.)

